# Problem when calculate simple sum with php

Tags: php

I have a strange problem, I try to calculate a basic sum with php, the result must be egal to zero, but php return a strange value :

```
$test = ((0.37)+(0.31)-(0.68));
echo 'test4 : '.$test;
```

The result must be "0", but `$test` return : "-1.1102230246252E-16"

I realy don't understand why, have you an idea ?

Thanks

https://extendsclass.com/php-bin/b731353

Comment: Short answer: when printing, you need to `round()` to the desired precision. When doing comparisons, you need to account for the error margin (do not `$a == $b`). When handling money, use integers.

Comment: thanks it's exactly this